# Simulate/Predict soccer standings after X rounds, based on current results/standing

Tags: r, predictive-models, simulation

How can I simulate/predict the soccer standings after a certain number of rounds, based on the currently played maches/standings.

I would like to do this with R.

After the first round, the result will not be precise, but after a few rounds, the simulation would probably become closer and closer to the real result.

Data example:

```
Round    Home team    Away team    Home score    Away score
1        Man Utd      Arsenal      3             1
1        Liverpool    Man City     0             1
1        Blackpool    Newcastle    0             0
1        QPR          Leeds        2             1
1        Chelsea      Wigan        4             0
2        Arsenal      Chelsea      2             2
2        Liverpool    Wigan        0             1
2        Blackpool    Leeds        2             2
.
.
.
.
And so on
```

Comment: So is it the fimal standings that you want to predict?  You didn't make it clear whether you wanted to predict the standings x games into the future or the final standings after the season is complete.  Of course as the season goes on there is less leeway for the standings to change and hence predictions should inprove greatly in accuracy as you approach the latter stages.

Comment: The thing is that I want to predict X number of rounds into the future, based on the current standings. This way I can predict the final standings, by predicting the missing number of rounds into the future, but also I will be able to use the same model on leagues where teams play 3 times against each other, like they do in the Danish league.

Comment: Well Okay. It seems that the model needs to depend on current standings and current won loss record record on teams remaining on the schedule. Also can you take account of player injuries and who is playing in goal for specific games. I am thinking thatto produce the best model and take advantage of existing data you want to predict individual games,take account of schedule in future rounds and whatever information is available about players availability for games, their past individual performance and who plays whom in each round. Player injury may be difficult to take advantage of.

Comment: You may have a handle on it for the next round but not for subsequent rounds when it may be ahrd to know when players will return from injuries and you can't condition on injuries that you don't know will occur.

Comment: Do you know anything about the methodology people use in the Danish league?

Comment: I want a simple model, only based on previous results, not players, I will not be able to maintain that many parameters. More about the danish Superliga structure here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Superliga#Structure

3 points for win, 1 point for a draw and 0 points for loss. Goal score (scored goals - lost goals) is the second parameter for standings. Points first, if equal then goal score.

Comment: Simple models give poor predictions. For a accurate predictions you should make the best use of available data.  But to advise you on modeling we need to know what data is available and how you want to put limits on modeling approached.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the Danish league structure.  My impression was that people do predicting there similar to what you want to do and I thought you might know something about the methodology that they use.

Comment: Well, the data I have access for, is for the Faroese league. There I have information on players, that played that match, how many goals, and when they were scored, substitutions, who and when, and yellow and red cards who and when. I probably also have access to information, if the goal was scored by penalty or not. But the problem is, that this will require me, to use a lot of time plotting in data for each round, and therefor I was looking for at simpler approach, which maybe would not be as accurate, bute useful tough. I do not know anything about the methodology they use.

Comment: I think you have a difficult problem.  To predict future standings accurately would requite exploiting all the good data you have available including player information on their performance and availability (i.e. injury status).

Comment: Actually my idea was to build it on the current standing, upcoming program and how well the teams are currently performing, based on wins/draws/losses during the last few rounds. 
Maybe with some kind of ranking, so that a win against a better placed team in the standings table last match counted more than a win against a lower placed team.
But I understand that there really is a need for more parameters, like injury status, and available players and so on.